# How to customize android chart engine pie chart

Tags: android, achartengine

1.How to display values on pie chart slice instead of labels.Here I am using following
but it is not working for me.

```
 seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
```

2.How to display pie chart left side of screen instead in the middle of the screen. I am using following but it is not working for me.

```
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{ 40, 90, 25, 10 });
        mRenderer.setScale(0.5f);
        mChartView.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you can download an intermediate version [here](http://www.achartengine.org/download/) for this.

For the second question, there is an opened issue for this, so it is not yet supported.